# How to create a grid of buttons in Tk with functions that are called using their grid positions as arguments

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter

I'm trying to make a simple gameboard using Tkinter with buttons that will change a single item in a 2D array, that corresponds to its position in the window - so I can check if the game's over by checking the array. This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
board = []
for x in range(8):
    board.append([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
def toggle(row,column):
    global board
    board[row][column] = (board[row][column]+1)%2
    print("-"*10)
    for x in board:
        for y in x:
            print(y, end="")
        print("")
    print("-"*10)
for x in range(8):
    for y in range(8):
        button = Button(master=root, text="--", command=lambda:toggle(y,x))
        button.grid(row=y,column=x)
root.mainloop()
```

However, this just ends up giving ALL the buttons the command toggle(7,7) and they all just toggle the final item of the final item in board. I tried an old question but I think it was python2, because the solution didn't change anything for my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the answer of [Bryan Oakley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7432/bryan-oakley) of the ["How to get grid information from pressed Button in tkinter?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31192508/6945651), the provided source is missing something.

When declaring the `command` attached to each button, it is necessary for the `lambda` to have a link between parameters `y,x` and the grid parameter `row=y,column=x`:

```
    button = Button(master=root, text=xy_text,
        command=lambda row=x, column=y: toggle(row, column))
    button.grid(row=y,column=x)
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick fix is:

```
def create_toggle_callback(y, x):
    return lambda: toggle(y, x)
```

and set the button command as:

```
button = Button(master=root, text="--", command=create_toggle_callback(y, x))
```

The reason for this is the way the variable scope works for closures in python. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938429/scope-of-python-lambda-functions-and-their-parameters) for instance. Basically we need to capture the value when defining the lambda and not capture a reference to the variable.